# MATLAB won't open after fresh installation!

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, matlab

I installed MATLAB on a new Ubuntu 14.04 installation. I don't get any errors, but when I try to run it in the terminal with the `matlab` command, the screen doesn't advance past the MATLAB logo:

[image]

I'm not sure what to do because it's not giving me any errors. I've already tried reinstalling MATLAB. Any advice would be appreciated as I'm unfamiliar with the Ubuntu environment.

Comment: Welcome! Copy the output and paste the *text* here would be gratefully :)

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: I've got the same problem and can't find a solution. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/568876/matlab-wont-start-after-clean-install

Answer (score 0):

Try running `matlab -desktop`, it should work.

Comment: did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is a permissions problem. The easiest thing to try is to start matlab by opening a new Terminal window (open a new Terminal window by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and executing:

```
sudo matlab
```

It worked for me, but it might take some time.