# Matlab won't start after clean install

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 64-bit, matlab

I am using 14.04.1 LTS on 64-bits and I installed Matlab R2014b 64-bit, but when I try to open it, I just get the picture saying that it's Matlab:

[image: picture]

and then nothing happens, even if I wait 20 minutes.

My question is similar to this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470406/matlab-wont-open-after-fresh-installation), but I tried opening it with `matlab -desktop` and was not successful. I also found this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92566-why-does-matlab-get-stuck-in-the-initializing-or-busy-state-or-take-a-long-time-to-start) in which multiple solutions are explained, but I do not know which applies in my case. I was thinking about the first one, regarding the MLM_LICENSE_FILE environment variable because there is none in my `.bashrc` file.

Could this be the problem? If yes, I do not have a `license.dat` file like in the solution explained in the link. If not, what else could it be?

Comment: Try <sudo matlab -desktop>

Comment: @Sina, that worked for me. Can this be made to work with the desktop icon?

Answer (score 1):

Sina's answer in the comments worked for me:

1st run:

```
$sudo matlab -desktop
```

this created a .matlab directory in my home folder

```
$sudo chown -R username:group .matlab
```

to get the launcher icons and everything else working normally...